# How is the image/object/view, image/object/truncated and image/object/difficult used during model training?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When preparing TF record data for model training with TF Object Detection there are following variables to be specified:

```
image/object/difficult
image/object/truncated
image/object/view
```

I'm wondering how are they used during the model training and also what are the possible values of the image/object/view variable, it feels like this should be some predefined set of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those fields are used during training, and for eval, only the "difficult" field is used.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a specific range of difficulty values or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Those are boolean fields saying whether the object is difficult or not.  You might take a look at the PASCAL VOC paper (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.5766&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a description of what this means.